# Save cookies in array to re-use later in php

Tags: php, cookies

I’m a novice in programming so don’t judge too strong!

On my localhost I have an HTML form with 2 input fields: $firstTerm and $secondTerm, and 4 buttons: Summ, Difference, Multiply, Divide.

```
<form>
    Enter first term: <input type="number" step="0.001" name="firstTerm">
    Enter second term: <input type="number" step="0.001" name="secondTerm">
    <button name="summ" id="summ">Summ</button>
    <button name="difference" id="difference">Difference</button>
    <button name="multiply" id="multiply">Multiply</button>
    <button name="divide" id="divide">Divide</button>
</form>
```

In that form, with GET method I’m returning the $result.

```
*if((isset($_GET['firstTerm']) && isset($_GET['secondTerm'])) && (isset ($_GET['summ']) || isset ($_GET['difference']) || isset ($_GET['multiply']) || isset ($_GET['divide']))){

    $keysGet = array_keys($_GET);

    $firstTerm = $_GET['firstTerm'];
    setcookie('firstTerm', $firstTerm, time()+604800);

    $secondTerm = $_GET['secondTerm'];
    setcookie('secondTerm', $secondTerm, time()+604800);

    $operation = $keysGet[2];
    switch ($operation) {
        case "summ": $result = $firstTerm + $secondTerm; break;
        case "difference": $result = $firstTerm - $secondTerm; break;
        case "multiply": $result = $firstTerm * $secondTerm; break;
        case "divide": $result = $firstTerm / $secondTerm; break;
    }

    setcookie('result', $result, time()+604800);

    echo "<h3>Your result is $result</h3>";
}*
```

With setcookie() php function I’m saving the users inputs.  In the browser with Developers Tools I can see the 3 values storred in $_COOKIE.

**Question:** how can I save all the users input (after pressing a button) during his calculations (when he is calculating on the same page in browser)?

With other words: each time when a button is pressed i need all the values from cookies to be stored in an other 3 arrays $firstTermCookie[] $secondTermCookie[] $resultCookie[], and from those 3 new arrays i need random values.

I’ve tried :

```
$firstTermCookie = [];
$secondTermCookie = [];
$resultCookie = [];
$firstTermCookie[] = $_COOKIE['firstTerm'];
$secondTermCookie[] = $_COOKIE['secondTerm'];
$resultCookie[] = $_COOKIE['result'];
```

but it stores just the values per operation, erasing previous values.
With a foreach $_COOKIE loop it stores the same value 3 times, also erasing previous values.
I’m aware of $_SESSION possibilities but I need to store them from $_COOKIE.

**Thank you in advance!**

P.S. 
This is my first question here, I’m sorry if I’ve done something wrong.

Comment: do you want save all results? against all 4 actions?

Comment: @devpro yes, the terms and the results against all 4 actions.

Comment: than why are using set cookies before your calculations?

Comment: you can add separate COOKIES for each function or if not than you can create an array with different index.

Comment: @devpro i need to re-use them later, when the user is on the same page.

Comment: @devpro as you can see i want each term in his own array: $firstTermCookie = [];
$secondTermCookie = [];
$resultCookie = [];

Comment: i have sent you a solution, please try, i hope this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how cookies work. From the [documenation of `setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed **on the next page load** with the `$_COOKIE` or `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` arrays.

So the `$_COOKIE` is set when the page loads, due to the stateless nature of the web. Hence you'll be able to see your `$_COOKIE` values when the **page loads again**.

Use `var_dump($_COOKIE);` to see what's inside the array. And for your purpose you should use `$_SESSION` instead.

Comment: i read that, i don't intent to use cookies immediately. After 3-4 calculations i want to store each previous terms in its own array, and later to work with values from those 3 new arrays: $firstTermCookie[], $secondTermCookie[], $resultCookie[].

Comment: @S.M. It's not possible. Since you **reload** the page for each calculation, hence after each calculation these 3 arrays `$firstTermCookie[]`, `$secondTermCookie[]` and `$resultCookie[]` will be overridden with new values.

Comment: i thought that if $_GET array stores diffrent values each time when it's called, then it must be a possibilitie to assign those diffrent values to different global variables(in my case arrays). I was considerring also the GLOBAL mode, but it seems that it will work similary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if((isset($_GET['firstTerm']) && isset($_GET['secondTerm'])) && (isset ($_GET['summ']) || isset ($_GET['difference']) || isset ($_GET['multiply']) || isset ($_GET['divide']))){

    $keysGet = array_keys($_GET);

    $firstTerm = $_GET['firstTerm'];
    $secondTerm = $_GET['secondTerm'];


    $operation = $keysGet[2];

    switch ($operation) {
        case "summ": 
        $result = $firstTerm + $secondTerm; 
        setcookie('firstTerm_summ', $firstTerm, time()+604800);
        setcookie('secondTerm_summ', $secondTerm, time()+604800);
        setcookie('result_summ', $result, time()+604800);

        break;
        case "difference": $result = $firstTerm - $secondTerm; 
        setcookie('firstTerm_difference', $firstTerm, time()+604800);
        setcookie('secondTerm_summ', $secondTerm, time()+604800);
        setcookie('result_difference', $result, time()+604800);
        break;
        case "multiply": $result = $firstTerm * $secondTerm; 
        setcookie('firstTerm_multiply', $firstTerm, time()+604800);
        setcookie('secondTerm_multiply', $secondTerm, time()+604800);
        setcookie('result_multiply', $result, time()+604800);
        break;
        case "divide": $result = $firstTerm / $secondTerm; 
        setcookie('firstTerm_divide', $firstTerm, time()+604800);
        setcookie('secondTerm_divide', $secondTerm, time()+604800);
        setcookie('result_divide', $result, time()+604800);
        break;
    }
    echo "<h3>Your result is $result</h3>";
}
```

Comment: it is a solution to 4 diffrent operations made just once for each other, but when a operation is repeated i don't have the possibility to store previous terms of the same operation.